# Getting output from a string variable, and remove spaces

Tags: bash

Hi this one got me scratching my head. The following bash code gives me the correct output but with a little twist.

```
names="fred bob harry george"

for i in $names
do
  echo $i
done
```

Which is fine except I want to use output in a directory path, then the problem is that the first item in list *fred* becomes *fred_* with a space (_) then my script fails.

Is there a way to get just the name in $i without space?

Comment: Please [edit] and post the code that fails and the error you got. Get familiar with the concept of [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659). For now it's not clear what space you are talking about.

Comment: @Kamil_Maciorowski is not wrong.  A better question was in order.. but I think I understand what you are asking for.. Try this? `echo "${i// /}"`  It uses a regular expression to replace a space '/ /' with nothing '//'

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a `for` loop on file-names with spaces in them.
The problem is that blank is a separator.

The `for` loop uses the `$IFS` variable for field separators,
which by default is set to the space character.

To avoid the problem, you may do something similar to:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for i in $names
do
  echo "$i"
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

For more info see for example the article
[BASH Shell: For Loop File Names With Spaces](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html).